# Crash in GStreamer qmlglsink pipeline dynamically rebind to different GstGLVideoItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, gstreamer

I've used one of existing qmlglsink examples to stream video feed from 4 IP Cameras.
4 Pipelines are created before engine load.

```
for(int i = 0; i < maxCameras; ++i) {
    GstElement* pipeline = gst_pipeline_new (NULL);
    GstElement* src = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsrc", NULL);
    GstElement* parse = gst_element_factory_make ("jpegparse", NULL);
    GstElement* decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("jpegdec", NULL);
    GstElement* glcolorconvert = gst_element_factory_make ("glcolorconvert", NULL);
    GstElement* glupload = gst_element_factory_make ("glupload", NULL);
    GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("qmlglsink", NULL);

    g_assert (src && parse && decoder && glupload && glcolorconvert && sink);

    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (src), "port", startingPort + i, NULL);

    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (sink), "sync", FALSE, NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), src, parse, decoder, glupload, glcolorconvert, sink, NULL);
    if (!gst_element_link_many ( src, parse, decoder, glupload, glcolorconvert, sink, NULL)) {
        qDebug() << "Linking GStreamer pipeline elements failed";
    }

    sinks.insert(std::make_pair(QString::number(startingPort+i), sink));
    pipelines.insert(std::make_pair(QString::number(startingPort+i), pipeline));
}
```

In Qml sink is connected and processed with

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import CustomProject 1.0
import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GLVideoItem 1.0

Item {
    id: root

    signal clicked()
    required property int udpPort
    property var camConnect: undefined
    onUdpPortChanged: { setupConnection(); }

    onVisibleChanged: {
        if (visible) { setupConnection();
        } else { camConnect = undefined }
    }

    GstGLVideoItem {
        id: videoItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        function connect() {
            CameraSinksFactory.connectSink(this, udpPort)
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            CameraSinksFactory.stopPipeline(udpPort)
            root.clicked()
        }
    }

    function setupConnection() {
        if (udpPort <= 0 || !root.visible) return;
        videoItem.connect()
        root.camConnect = CameraSinksFactory.getCamConnection(udpPort);
        root.camConnect.resolutionX =// - 15 root.width
        root.camConnect.resolutionY = root.height
        root.camConnect.bitrate = 15000000
        root.camConnect.streaming = root.visible
        CameraSinksFactory.startPipeline(udpPort)
    }
}
```

Problem: Main screen display 4 (2x2 grid) items using Model (which provides udpPort as unique ID). When User clicks on one Item - feed from this camera should fill whole screen. In Examples they create GridLayout with 4/6 explicit items and just manipulate their visiblity (in effect clicked item is only one remaining and take whole screen).
In my case - I'm using separate Item for full screen view. So I'm disabling streaming (CamConnection class communicating with Cameras and sending commands) and hide GridView. New **GstGLVideoItem** binds to qmlglsink in pipeline.
Everything is OK, until I repeat click sequence (back to GridView and to fullview). Every time it ends with:

> Bail out! ERROR:../ext/qt/gstqsgtexture.cc:134:virtual void
> GstQSGTexture::bind(): code should not be reached
>
> ** (KMS:20495): CRITICAL **: 15:47:36.937: gst_video_frame_map_id: assertion 'info->width <= meta->width' failed
> ** ERROR:../ext/qt/gstqsgtexture.cc:134:virtual void GstQSGTexture::bind(): code should not be reached

From plugins code analysis it's happening when INFO (image size read from CAPS) is bigger then size in metadata in provided buffer. Which is understandable - buffer is too small.
I used **GST_DEBUG=4/5/6/7** and logs confirm that autodetected caps are matching request in commands sent to camera.
I can use example, but project assumes another panel with those cameras - so above problem will hit me in near future.

How to make this whole setup working?  How to rebind pipeline qmlglsink to new QML VideoItem safely?

Comment: Previously when I stopPileline I set state **GST_STATE_PAUSED**, when I change it to GST_STATE_NULL it seems that problem is gone.     

Could it be that - when paused - buffer size between pipeline elements wasn't changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

- set `gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);`, change sink widget to new item and start pipeline `gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);`
- use Qt 5 MediaPlayer with gst-pipeline as source. When visible set **source** and execute **start()**. When not visible reset **source** to **empty** (important) and execute stop().

In general - possible benefits from NOT creating pipeline each time are not worth hassle when we dynamically assign new QML Item to pipeline sink.